# How can I combine two radio buttons to show the same element, if they are set to "Yes"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

Here is what I have, in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='DifficultyObtainingCMELicenseRenewal']").change(function() {
      $("#DifficultyObtainingCME").toggle(this.value == "Yes");
    });
    $("input[name='DifficultyObtainingCMEBoardCertification']").change(function() {
      $("#DifficultyObtainingCME").toggle(this.value == "Yes");
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <tr>
    <th><label>Do you have difficulty obtaining enough CME required for Iowa license renewal?</label></th>
    <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="DifficultyObtainingCMELicenseRenewal" value="Yes" class="checkbox"/> Yes</label><br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="DifficultyObtainingCMELicenseRenewal" value="No" class="checkbox"/> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><label>Do you have difficulty obtaining enough CME required for your specialty board certification/re-certification?</label></th>
    <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="DifficultyObtainingCMEBoardCertification" value="Yes" class="checkbox"/> Yes</label><br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="DifficultyObtainingCMEBoardCertification" value="No" class="checkbox"/> No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="DifficultyObtainingCME" style="display:none">
    <th class="altTH"><label>Please elaborate on the difficulties you are experiencing:</label></th>
    <td class="altTD">
        <cftextarea name="DifficultyObtainingCMEOther" rows="3" cols="20"></cftextarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

So right now if you press "Yes" on one of the boxes it shows the extra field, but then pressing No on the other makes it disappear, and vice versa. How do I make it so, it stays open as long as either one of them is set to "Yes"?

Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/madcaesar/hcZXf/

Comment: It's often times very helpful if you provide an example via http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure either "Yes" option is checked when the change happens:

```
var thingToToggle = $("#DifficultyObtainingCME");
var allRadios = $('input[type="radio"]');

allRadios.change(function () {
    if (allRadios.filter(function () {
        return this.checked && this.value === 'Yes';
    }).length > 0) {
        thingToToggle.show();
    } else {
        thingToToggle.hide();
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JptF8/

Comment: You could also get only the "yes" buttons with something like `var yesRadios = $('input[type="radio"][value="Yes"]')`...

Comment: This doesn't work because I have other "yes" "no" buttons on the form, so it has to be specific to those two, by name.

Comment: @Amir just modify the selector for `allRadios` to specify the name attribute. `[name="whatever"]`

Comment: @jbabey you mean like this?: var allRadios = $('input[type="radio"][name="DifficultyObtainingCMELicenseRenewal"],input[type="radio"][name="DifficultyObtainingCMEBoardCertification"]'); 

It seems to be working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
if ($('input[type="radio"][value="Yes"]:checked').length > 0) {
    $("#DifficultyObtainingCME").show();
} else {
    $("#DifficultyObtainingCME").hide();
}
});
```

Of course, if you add more radio buttons later this will apply to those too. In that case, add a class to the ones you want this apply to (e.g. $('.toggleRadioClass[value="Yes"]:checked')). Not sure what the $("#DifficultyObtainingCME").toggle(this.value == "Yes"); is supposed to do, but my code will actually show and hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

Base the visibility off of the presence of `:checked` yes-radios:

```
var $radios = $("input[name^='DifficultyObtainingCME']"),
    $toggle = $("#DifficultyObtainingCME");

$radios.on("change", function(){
    $toggle.toggle(!!$radios.filter("[value='Yes']:checked").length);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wD8D/3/